# Fortinet FortiWifi 20C Reset

Tags: wifi, fortinet, password-reset, fortigate

I've tried multiple times to reset the login on our router, 5 seconds on the reset button, 30 seconds on the reset button, power cycle. No matter what I google and do, I can't seem to get this thing to reset the login.

I've been reading from a few places that the username is maintainer and the password is bcpb[serial]. I've tried with a dash bcpb-serial, tried with bcpb[firstthree]-[rest] and I've tried all in one with no dashes. All is caps for the serial. I'm at a loss. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

THE ANswer is 
Username: Maintainer
Password: bcpbFGTXXXXXXXXXXXX

the hard thing though it needs to be done 14 seconds after the device boots.
The easiest way is to connect the console cable to the Fortigate's console port and use PUTTY to connect to the serial port on your pc.
any later than 14 seconds and the device has gone too far and youll need to reboot the device and try again.

Comment: Eventually it came down to just calling the IT company that set it up. Thanks!